# Cannot clone gitlab project via SSH

Tags: ssh, gitlab

I am trying to use SSH method to clone gitlab project, and I follow the instructions in the website https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/ but it failed, below is the log that I run the command “ssh -Tvvv git@gitlab.com”, I have tried on several computers but the same problem happened. could anyone help me to figure out the problem, thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swb2t.png)

Best Regards,
Simon

Comment: yes, the key pair has been created and I have copied the public key to gitlab. In the line 11"debug1: identity file /home/simon/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub type 3" of the log, it seems that it has found the public key in local computer

Comment: have you tried `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` ?

Comment: @asitdhal It works after I try StrictHostKeyChecking=no, and then I change it to yes, it still works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to answer yes at the "`The authenticity of host 'gitlab.com' can't be established`" step.

If you don't, the SSH connection won't complete, and the clone will fail.

That step should be asked only once, meaning your next `ssh -Tvvv git@gitlab.com` should not ask you again the same question, since `~/.known_hosts` will have been updated.

This is safer than `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`.